# Dynamically update css properties in scss file (Angular 2+)

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a .scss file which is holding all the application css classes. There is an admin portal which user can set the properties like font size, text color e.t.c. When the application loads, client will be receiving these properties in a form of a key value object.

ex:

`properties:{
'font-size':26,
'color':'blue'
}`

I want to override these properties with defaults holding in my scss file.
I searched a bit and found that css variables is one of the option. But with that we will loose the support for IE11 as it does not work in IE 11.

Is there is any other way where i can look in to. Or is there any way where I can build the css file when i receive this object response from server.

Kindly help and suggest some approaches to deal with this.

Comment: Tried [ngStyle]?

Comment: An alternative would be: e.g. [ngClass]="Config.IsDarkMode ? header : dark-header"

Comment: [ngStyle] i have to go to each component and apply it. I am looking for right approach.

Comment: @mamichels I do not follow you. Can you please elaborate your example? Or is it same as mentioned by above guy named 'swoox' ?

Comment: ngClass applies css classes programmatically while ngStyle will do the individual styling. https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

This may be a solution depending on your use case. If you really want more flexibility like pixel perfect font-sizes you will have to write your own custom logic or find a adequate framework for it.